# How to view python application logs on logcat

Tags: python, android, kivy, logcat

I have installed a working app written in python/kivy that worked on Android 8.1 on a new Samsung A71 phone that runs Android 10q. Now certain features related to file browsing is not working.  I have print statements that can help debug the problem. But these print statements are not visible on logcat. So I have no way of debugging the problem.What can I do to get around this problem?

Comment: Have a look at [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=O_ROwKkd0aA). I also use this logviewer to debug. I'm not sure if logcat shows print statements or not but this one does. Give it a shot

Comment: Good application.  It looks like a permission issue.  Getting audit error type 1327. Now need to figure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get printed text output in logcat by using Warning and/or Exception like this:

```
import warnings
warnings.warn('your message')
try:
    # some statement that is causing an OSError say
except OSError as e:
    raise Exception('your custom message') from e
```

then

```
adb logcat | egrep 'Exception|Warning'
```